Is there a way to show the power inline configuration for all ports on cisco switch?
On a Cisco C9200 I would like to show the power configuration for all ports so I can parse the output in a script. I know I can use show run and see the power inline configuration. But I'm looking for a command that will specifically list all ports and their power settings, like power inline port 2-event or power inline static max.
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/10
 switchport trunk native vlan 1001
 switchport trunk allowed vlan 12,220,1001
 switchport mode trunk
 power inline port 2-event
 spanning-tree portfast

Any commands for that?

sh run | i interface|power 

@RonTrunk I know we can do that, but this is not a "purpose driven" command. This results in erroneous outputs not related to the interface or its power settings, because any line with interface or power in it is output. It is not reliable. I am looking for a specific command that outputs formatted information about power settings on interfaces.

There is no command to do exactly what you want.  One suggestion that will get you pretty close is
show running-config | include ^interface|^( )power

That filters for lines that begin with interface or begin with a space and the word power.  For example:
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/9
 power inline never


I think the command you are looking for is "show power inline { gig... }". This will show you the max power in watts that the port can put out and also will show you how much power in watts it is currently putting out if any. "show power inline" by itself will show all ports on the device.

Thanks for the suggestion. This command doesn't actually show the configured settings. Such as power inline static max or power inline port 2-event. I guess I'm just going to have to parse the show run.
